# React Hook Invalid Usage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

I've been having an issue which returns the classic Hook issue:
×
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Now it appears iv'e narrowed it done and it's my  div, which is a div with animated css. Please see the code below for the styled component:

```
const BackDrop = styled(motion.div)`
  position: absolute;
  width: 160%;
  height: 550px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
  top: -290px;
  left: -70px;
  background: #8360c3; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #2ebf91,
    #8360c3
  ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
`;
```

And it's inside of a function which I call to the App.js:

```
export function AccountBox(props) {
  const { initialActive } = props;
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(
    initialActive ? initialActive : "signin"
  );

  const playExpandingEffect = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setExpanded(false);
    }, expandingTransition.duration * 1000 - 1500);
  };

  const switchActive = (active) => {
    setTimeout(() => setActive(active), 400);
  };

  const switchToSignup = () => {
    playExpandingEffect();
    switchActive("signup");
  };

  const switchToSignin = () => {
    playExpandingEffect();
    switchActive("signin");
  };

  const contextValue = {
    switchToSignup,
    switchToSignin,
    playExpandingEffect,
  };

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <BoxContainer>
        <TopContainer>
          <BackDrop
            variants={backdropVariants}
            transition={expandingTransition}
            initial={false}
            animate={isExpanded ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}
          />
          {active === "signin" && (
            <>
              <HeaderContainer>
                <HeaderText>Welcome</HeaderText>
                <HeaderText>Back</HeaderText>
              </HeaderContainer>
              <SmallText>Please sign-in to continue!</SmallText>
            </>
          )}
          {active === "signup" && (
            <>
              <HeaderContainer>
                <HeaderText>Create </HeaderText>
                <HeaderText>Account</HeaderText>
              </HeaderContainer>
              <SmallText>Please sign-up to continue!</SmallText>
            </>
          )}
        </TopContainer>
        <InnerContainer>
          {active === "signin" && <LoginForm />}
          {active === "signup" && <SignupForm />}
        </InnerContainer>
      </BoxContainer>
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now is the issue that i'm calling the Hook incorrectly? I can see some documentation online however I can't figure out why this is an issue as it's called in the function.

Does anybody knows!

Comment: where's the hook?

Comment: Which hook are you referring to?

Comment: never mind. the setState hook in the timeout might actually be the one throwing the error. You are calling a hook in a setTimeout callback. I think that's the problem.

Comment: The error should reference a line number.

Comment: @DovRine Doing that is perfectly fine. The problem is OP is using a hook call *outside* a component function, exactly like the error says. A "hook call" is something like `useState(...)`, not calling the setter it returns.

Comment: @ChrisG: That's what I originally thought, so I was looking for a custom hook somewhere and didn't see one.

Comment: I guess I should go to bed...

Comment: @DovRine so would be it seem to be that I'm incorrectly using it. Sorry I'm very new to React! So would the best change be to look through my jsx and see iv'e called a React hook and not coded in the setter? Can you see the error already in this code. Thanks for the help already!

Comment: @n_d22: no. as ChrisG said, post the line of the error

Comment: @DovRine oh, sorry! The first part it shows is: import App from './App';
   5 | import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
   6 | 
>  7 | ReactDOM.render(
   8 |   <React.StrictMode>
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </React.StrictMode>,

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace in the original question